# Cannot read f1-score from csv file

Tags: python, pandas

i am reading classification_report file after doing 10 fold cv

```
for i in _all_files:
    print(i)
    df = pd.read_csv(i)


    saved_column = df.f1-score
    a = saved_column[5]
    li.append(a)
```

I want to add f1-score and find mean. But I am getting below error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'f1'
```

I am able to fetch accuracy, precision and recall score using above code but bot f2-score.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
saved_column = df['f1-score']
```

Hyphens are not allowed as part of an attribute name.  That is, using the dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way is necessary:

```
saved_column = df['f1-score']
a = saved_column.iloc[5]
```